# Can you ask how to pass a stage? What tag should I use?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

If you want to ask about a certain objective, or what do you have to do to pass a stage in a video game, is this allowed on Arqade? If so, which tag do you use for the question when it isn't one of the best known games and there isn't a tag?

Comment: Related: [I want to ask a question about a game which has no tag yet, how should I tag it?](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/813/28182)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **It is perfectly fine** to ask about any (game-related) problem you encounter when playing a game.
  As a heads-up, asking about tasks that are solved using simple or obvious solutions, or solutions that can easily be found online, might get you some downvotes - reversely, harder, well-known, or obscure solutions, or ones that hard to find online, might get you more upvotes. We expect users to have done some research before asking questions here.
- As for the tags you use, as long as you cannot create them yourself, **a user with higher reputation will edit it in**.
  **You don't have to use a specific tag for the *nature* of the problem** you're facing, though. If they exist and are necessary or helpful, you can edit them in later, or someone else might do so.